# disable hdmi audio output

Tags: unity, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

Ubuntu 17.04 64bit

I use only my spdif output for sound. I recently changed my monitor and this one is plugged int the DisplayPort.

Now, everytime I turn the screen on, Ubuntu switch from the spdif to the Displayport audio output. It's really annoying.

[image: Unity Control Center]

The Unity control center has noting to select a default output or to disable an output.

I was told to use Pavucontrol, strangely it only display the output selected by Unity-control-center. It won't display both output at the same time and the "set as fallback" switch does nothing (and by it's label only I'm not sure what it should do).

[image: Unity Control Center]

What can I do to keep spdif always selected?